# How do I schedule an scp job on Windows?

Tags: windows, automation, scheduler, scp

First of all, I am not an expert programmer, and I don't know much of the programmer's lingo. So please bear with me.
I am using Cygwin on windows, to copy a file from home directory to a remote server (which uses Linux) using SCP. I need to do this every day and so I want to automate it. I know how to schedule tasks in task scheduler, but I don't know what kind of file to save an scp command as. Please help? Oh and I don't have admin access, so I cannot install or use third party applications

Comment: @arkascha Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

First add Cygwin to your Windows Environment Variables. You can find directions on how to do that [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41382/how-to-use-linux-commands-in-windows-with-cygwin/) (the directions you need are almost all the way at the bottom of the page). Now you should be able to run Linux commands from the command prompt. Simply make a .bat file in notepad with the commands you need to run. It should look something like this:

```
scp /cygdrive/d/test.txt <linux ip>:/etc/var/test/test.txt
```

Then use task scheduler to run the .bat file.